# Oracle:if left join table return no rows then change to another left join table

Tags: oracle, left-join

I have two query as below and both of them work well. Now  I need to combine them and if the first select find rows then no need to run the second select

1.

```
select f.*, o.org_sn, ttt.name linkman_name, ttt.phone phone_num
from td_archive_feedback f
         left join TD_SM_ORG o
                   on f.recv_org_id = o.org_id
         left join (--if this select returns no row , then change.if find matching rows then don't change
                    select wm_concat(linkman_name) name,
                           wm_concat(phone_num) phone,
                           org_id
                    from (select linkman_name, phone_num, LINK_ORG_ID, org_id
                          from TD_SM_LINKMAN
                          where STATE = '2'
                            and (LINK_ORG_ID = #link_org_id)) t
                    group by org_id) ttt
                   on ttt.org_id = o.org_id
                   --
         left join td_sm_dict_item di
                   on o.org_level = di.item_id
where f.businessid = #businiessid
```

2. 

```
select f.*, o.org_sn, ttt.name linkman_name, ttt.phone phone_num
from td_archive_feedback f
         left join TD_SM_ORG o
                   on f.recv_org_id = o.org_id
         left join (--if the first left join return no rows ,then change to this 
                    select wm_concat(linkman_name) name,
                           wm_concat(phone_num) phone,
                           t.org_id
                    from (
                        select linkman_name, phone_num, LINK_ORG_ID, org_id
                          from TD_SM_LINKMAN
                          where STATE = '2'
                            and (LINK_ORG_ID is null or LINK_ORG_ID = '')) t
                    group by t.org_id) ttt
                   on ttt.org_id = o.org_id
                      --
         left join td_sm_dict_item di
                   on o.org_level = di.item_id
where f.businessid = #businessid;
```

Just like I remarked, if

```
select wm_concat(linkman_name) name,.... where  STATE = '2'
                            and (LINK_ORG_ID = #link_org_id)) t
```

... returns no rows,

I want to change this to:

```
select  wm_concat(linkman_name) name,.... where  STATE = '2' and (LINK_ORG_ID is null or LINK_ORG_ID = '')) t.
```

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Or condition:

```
select f.*, o.org_sn, ttt.name linkman_name, ttt.phone phone_num
from td_archive_feedback f
         left join TD_SM_ORG o
                   on f.recv_org_id = o.org_id
         left join (--if this select returns no row , then change 
                    select wm_concat(linkman_name) name,
                           wm_concat(phone_num) phone,
                           org_id
                    from (select linkman_name, phone_num, LINK_ORG_ID, org_id
                          from TD_SM_LINKMAN
                          where STATE = '2'
                            and (
                            (LINK_ORG_ID = #link_org_id) or
                             (LINK_ORG_ID is null or LINK_ORG_ID = '')
                             ) t
                    group by org_id) ttt
                   on ttt.org_id = o.org_id
                   --
         left join td_sm_dict_item di
                   on o.org_level = di.item_id
where f.businessid = #businiessid
```

Comment: thanks for you help.but i need if first select find rows then don't run the another. if use union ,then i will some extra rows which i don't need.

Comment: Difference between Select 1 and Select 2 is only in terms of where STATE = '2'
                            and (LINK_ORG_ID = #link_org_id) and STATE = '2'
                            and (LINK_ORG_ID is null or LINK_ORG_ID = '') query. You should use or condition i.e. if first condition is true then system will not look for 2nd condition.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment, please check

Comment: thanks for your kindness. I just check the updated. but the results returns the extral linkman. i need that if one linkman's link_org_id = 'xxxx' and his org_id = td_archive_feedback 's recv_org_id , then no need to find others linkman . but follow the update , the results shows 2nd condition also run. i get other linkman whose link_org_id is null or link_org_id = ' '.

Comment: Its better to add some sample data and expected result to your question.

Comment: i just simplify my question and give some data samples, here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499587/oracle-union-all-query-1-and-query-2-want-to-minus-some-rows-if-query-1-have-ro)